# Translate column names of a dataframe

Tags: pandas

My df is this:

```
   December January
1         1       1
2         2       2
3         3       3
4         4       4
5         5       5
6         6       6
7         7       7
8         8       8
9         9       9
10       10      10
```

I want to translate my column names from english to spanish. So i did this code:

```
import googletrans
from googletrans import Translator

translator = Translator()

df.rename(columns=lambda x: translator.translate(x, dest='es').text, inplace=True)
```

But i get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

I cannot see the problem. I would appreciate any advise.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try replace `columns=lambda x: translator.translate(x, dest='es').text` with `colums={x: translator.translate(x, dest='es').text for x in df.columns}`

Comment: @oskros i got the same error message :/

Comment: Can you make a mock of your dataframe, then I can test it locally